# Using Postmates API in a rails app with HTTParty

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, httparty

I've been working on integrating Postmates with my ecommerce rails application for on demand deliveries. I've built a controller and view for testing purposes and configured it in my routes file (built in my dev environment). For reference, here is the documentation from Postmates: [docs](https://postmates.com/developer/docs) and here is a technical blogpost: [blog](http://blog.postmates.com/post/104856343907/a-technical-perspective-on-the-postmates-api)

Routes file:

```
resources :postmates do
    member do 
        post 'get_delivery'
    end
  end
```

The controller:

```
require 'httparty'
require 'json'

class PostmatesController < ApplicationController

  def get_delivery
    api_key = **hidden**
    @customer = 'cus_K8mRn4ovuNyNKV'
    @urlstring_to_post = 'https://api.postmates.com/v1/customers/' + @customer + '/delivery_quotes'

    @result = HTTParty.post(@urlstring_to_post.to_str,
      :body => { :dropoff_address => "205 E 95th Street, New York, NY 10128", 
                 :pickup_address => "619 W 54th St, New York, NY 10019" 
                }.to_json,
      :basic_auth => { :username => api_key },
      :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' })
  end

end
```

The view:

```
<div class="container">
  <%= form_tag url_for(:controller => 'postmates', :action => 'get_delivery'), :method => 'post' do %>
  <%= submit_tag "Get Delivery", :action => 'get_delivery', :controller => 'postmates'%>  
  <% end %>
</div>

<p>Result: <%= @result %></p>
```

Here is the response back from the api:

```
{"kind"=>"error", "code"=>"invalid_params", "params"=>{"dropoff_address"=>"This field is required.", "pickup_address"=>"This field is required."}, "message"=>"The parameters of your request were invalid."}
```

It seems to me that **the dropoff and pickup address are not being submitted in the HTTP request**. Can anyone tell me if I'm making some minor syntax error or something? The fact that I'm getting this  response means that my authentication is fine and so is the url. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're posting JSON data to the API, while the documentation (https://postmates.com/developer/docs#basics) says you should POST the data as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

I'm not really familiar with HTTParty, but you can probably just remove the `.to_json` and don't specify the content-type header.

Comment: Awesome man that worked! Thanks a lot! This was my first attempt at using an API so it has been a struggle. Hopefully this will help other inexperienced rails devs who want to use Postmates.

Answer (score 3):

Unrelated to your question, but you shouldn't publicly post your API key. ;)