# Rails - Don't want to create a database with only one field, but don't know any other methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm trying to have an "address" input field on one of my view page, and i want to use that "address" as one of my parameters in my API call.

I am not sure if I should create a whole new controller/model just for this one address field, and I am sure there are definitely better ways to do this.

The idea came from [Postmates Website](https://postmates.com/), where on the homepage you can enter your address and Postmates will give you a list of available delivery services. I am looking for something similar to this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you just using the address as a parameter to help you find other information, or do you need to store the address for other purposes?

Comment: one of the parameter for the postmates API call is "delivery_address", and I intend to use the "address" field above in that field. If you take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27850845/using-postmates-api-in-a-rails-app-with-httparty), you can imagine that I simply want to replace the :drop_off address with "address" above.

Sorry if that's confusing

Comment: The stackoverflow post you just linked to is about interacting with the existing Postmates site. You're not trying to do that, you're actually trying to make a similar app, right? If so, and you don't need to store the address, you don't need to make a model for it. You can just set up a `GET` route that accepts a parameter and then access it with a corresponding action in an existing controller or a new controller.

Answer (score 0):

Create a form who's method points to one of your controller actions and then use the data from the form in that action.

So:

```
<form action="route/that/handles/delivery/address" method="get">
  <input name="address">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then in your controller action:

```
def handle_address
  params[:address] // do stuff with this
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need just one field on the table? 
I agree it might be better to just send and update the parameter you want to change by modifying the controller instead.